# Can anyone please translate this text? I have tried google and yandex translator but none of them is clear

Tags: перевод

Есть неориентированный граф с n вершинами и m рёбрами. Поступают запросы трёх видов: добавить ребро (x_i,y_i), удалить ребро (x_i,y_i), и проверить, связаны или нет вершины x_i и y_i путём.

Если бы запросы удаления отсутствовали, то решением задачи была бы известная структура данных disjoint-set-union (система непересекающихся множеств). Однако при наличии удалений задача значительно усложняется.

Сделаем следующим образом. В начале каждого блока запросов посмотрим, какие рёбра в этом блоке будут удаляться, и сразу удалим их из графа. Теперь построим систему непересекающихся множеств (dsu) на полученном графе.

Как мы теперь должны отвечать на очередной запрос из текущего блока? Наша система непересекающихся множеств "знает" обо всех рёбрах, кроме тех, что добавляются/удаляются в текущем блоке. Однако удаления из dsu нам делать уже не надо — мы заранее удалили все такие рёбра из графа. Таким образом, всё, что может быть — это дополнительные, добавляющиеся рёбра, которых может быть максимум \sqrt{m} штук.

Следовательно, при ответе на текущий запрашивающий запрос мы можем просто пустить обход в ширину по компонентам связности dsu, который отработает за O(\sqrt{m}), поскольку у нас в рассмотрении будут только O(\sqrt{m}) рёбер.

Comment: Did you really try to put this into Yandex Translate?  I did and it seems to me that the bulk of the paragraphs are translated in a reasonable way.

Comment: Ye, I did. But there were terms like "ribs" which confused me.

Comment: I got the same mistake, one time. The word for "edge" of a graph, ребро, also means rib. I still think it was a bit much to ask for a translation of all  5 paragraphs when you could have isolated the paragraph containing that error (and if you look on the Russian Wikipedia page for rib, from the English page, you would figure out the error). Anyway, this site is not meant to provide the full translation you requested, so be happy you got what you came for but don't ask something like that here again. See http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/110/what-should-our-faq-contain?rq=1.

Comment: I wonder how it helps learning Russian and in what way it can be interesting for other people.

Comment: Небольшое предупреждение: текст выглядит так, будто в нем пропустили целый абзац. Идея алгоритма в том, что исходный набор из m запросов делится на \sqrt{m} блоков по \sqrt{m} запросов каждый.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an undirected graph with *n* nodes and *m* edges. We can get three types of requests: add an edge (*x_i*,*y_i*), delete an edge (*x_i*,*y_i*), and check whether or not the nodes *x_i* and *y_i* are connected by a path.

If there were no deletion requests, than the well-known data structure disjoint-set-union (a system of nonintersecting subsets) would solve the problem. However, the occurrence of deletions makes the problem far more complicated.

Let's do the following. At the beginning of each request block we will check  which edges will be deleted in this block, and immediately delete them from the graph. Now let's build a system of nonintersecting subsets (a disjoint-set-union, DSU) on the graph we obtain.

How shall we respond to the successive requests from the current block? Our disjoint-set-union "knows" about all the edges except for ones that are added/deleted in the current block. But we don't need to perform deletions from the DSU, because we've already deleted all such edges from the graph. So, all we may get are new, additional edges, not more than \sqrt{*m*}.

Consequently, to respond to the currently handled request we can just launch a breadth-first search of the connected components of the DSU, that will be completed in time *O*(\sqrt{*m*}), because we have to deal with only *O*(\sqrt{*m*}) edges.